# How to disable an NSTextField and make it uneditable? [isEditable property not working]

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstextfield

I'm getting the promo code input in NSTextField and on clicking apply the promo code is applied.

At this point, my text field should be uneditable until the remove promo code is pressed. if remove promo code button is pressed the text field becomes editable. This works just like Zomato coupon codes apply and remove.

I tried isEditable = false but that doesn't work

```
@IBOutlet weak var promoCodeValidity: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var promoCode: NSTextField!

func applyCoupon(){
    let couponCode = promoCode.stringValue
    if let offer = bookingView!.applyOffer(offerCode:couponCode){
        promoCodeValidity.stringValue="Offer Applied "+String(offer)+"% Off"
        promoCode.isEditable=false
    }
    else{
        promoCodeValidity.stringValue="Offer Code Invalid"

    }
}
```

why isEditable doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try toggling the isEnabled property of the text field and then change the isEnabled property of the text field.
***i.e First disable the text field, then change the editable property of the text field and then again enable the text field.***
Hope this solves your problem.
I have attached a small code sample also :)

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    let textField = NSTextField()
    let button = NSButton()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
        textField.placeholderString = "ENTER PROMO CODE"
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textField.isEditable = true
        button.action = #selector(buttonClicked(_:))
        view.addSubview(textField)
        view.addSubview(button)
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil , attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 100).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive  = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: textField, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 20).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil , attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 50).isActive = true
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }
    @objc func buttonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        textField.isEnabled = false
        textField.isEditable = false
        textField.isEnabled = true
    }


}
```

Comment: Great Answer Thanks

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score -2):

```
add extention:
extension UITextField

{
    open override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.paste(_:)) || action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.cut(_:)) || action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.copy(_:)) || action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.select(_:)) || action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.selectAll(_:))  {
            return false
        }
        return false
}
}

and:
textFiled.isEditable = false
```

Comment: can u give this for MACOS im asking for NSTextField